# How to send headers from HTML / UI in an API request to server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, api, http

I want to add HTTP headers on every request from client. Not able to figure out how.

Had tried to add following script to HTML to set headers like:

```
<script>
    res.setHeader('Authorization', "I am JWT Bearer token");
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the javascript request. Something like $.ajax({ url: '....' })

Comment: I am using only what i wrote probaby i am missing smoething

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add headers while making an API call from AJax or other API request modules  for client-side and not via submiting `<form>` and adding action to your `<form>`

Via Ajax call you can do something like this:

```
<script>
 function submitForm() {
    var data = {};//Your JSON Data

    //You can make this a global variable to use everywhere.
    //Or you can make a function what will be responsible to make all aJax calls.
   //Function will receive 3 arguments: json data, success-callback and error-callback, or in place of call back you can use Promise. 
    var headers = {
        "Contect-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic : your auth"
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://google.com',
        type: 'POST',//'GET','PUT','DELETE'
        headers: headers,
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('error ',error);
        }
    });
  }
</script>
```

You need to call this function in place of using

`<form action="submitAPI" method="POST"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>`

Use this:

`<form><input onclick="submitForm()" value="Submit" /></form>`